# edx student module integrity error

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python, edx

I am working with **`edx developer`** stack and when I tried to insert an entry to `StudentModule` I'm getting this **error** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 137, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 377, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 551, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1593, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 912, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 114, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '5-i4x://Organization/EDDC/course/2015-
Organization/EDDC/2015' 
for key 'courseware_studentmodule_student_id_635d77aea1256de5_uniq'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `StudentModule` model with `student` foreign key which has `unique=True` property.  If so then you attempt to save `StudentModule` with duplicate `student`.

Note that you table can containg only one record with `student == None` (just in case if your `stident` foreign key has `null=True`).